# Getting server errors when trying to add an intro/full article image to article (J3)

Tags: media-manager, nginx

On one of my servers (Plesk on Linode) I have several Joomla sites.
Sometime in the past couple weeks we are no longer able to select (or upload) an intro or full article image to an article. It is happening on all J3 sites on this server (not on the J4 sites).

Specifically when you click the SELECT button next to the intro image entry box on the article's Images and Links tab, the normal pop-up/modal window appears however, the folder ad files areas are all empty. And the Cancel/Refresh/Insert buttons don't do anything.

This is obviously a server configuration issue in some way but have yet to figure out example where the issue might be.

The server logs for one of the domains from the point that we click the SELECT button to select an image (and the pop-up/modal opens) is listed below. Which seems to show that it is a problem with the server and specifically with nginx.

Additionally we are noticing problems the JCE Editor (nothing is displaying). And were getting similar nginx errors (connection refused).

Has anyone here run across this sort of problem and/or errors?
We have several other similarly configured servers that are having no problems.
And it appears that the problems are limited to Joomla. We have several other web systems running on different domains on the same server and none of them are having problems. Just the J3 sites are having issues.(All are running J3.10.11).

Any ideas or even thoughts of where to look would be welcome.

Here is the server logs from the point of the error happening (Domain and local IP addresses changed to protect the not-so-innocent server :-) )

```
2022-12-13 06:21:13 
Access  
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
200 
GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin.loadlanguages&lang=en&plugin=browser&standalone=1&context=22&15f462eea0ca946548e59238cbe7080b=1 HTTP/1.0    https://MYDOMAIN/administrator/index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin.display&element=jform_images_image_intro&mediatype=images&converted=1&context=22&plugin=browser&standalone=1&15f462eea0ca946548e59238cbe7080b=1&client=1&fieldid=jform_images_image_intro&ismoo=0&folder=   
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0    
3.68 K  
Apache SSL/TLS access

2022-12-13 06:21:13 
Error   
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
502 
GET /components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/plugins/browser/css/browser.min.css?363878d4dc65b6f2a6ef4aa6bd94c6a4 HTTP/2.0   
https://MYDOMAIN/administrator/index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin.display&element=jform_images_image_intro&mediatype=images&converted=1&context=22&plugin=browser&standalone=1&15f462eea0ca946548e59238cbe7080b=1&client=1&fieldid=jform_images_image_intro&ismoo=0&folder=   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0    
150     
nginx SSL/TLS access

2022-12-13 06:21:13 
Error   
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
502 
GET /components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/plugins/browser/js/popup.min.js?f8f9cb75d3dc6e99d4554bdeb96849ee HTTP/2.0   
https://MYDOMAIN/administrator/index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin.display&element=jform_images_image_intro&mediatype=images&converted=1&context=22&plugin=browser&standalone=1&15f462eea0ca946548e59238cbe7080b=1&client=1&fieldid=jform_images_image_intro&ismoo=0&folder=   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0    
150     
nginx SSL/TLS access

2022-12-13 06:21:13 
Error   
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
502 
GET /components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/plugins/browser/js/browser.js?d2b6d1d9821167cecdce5b93948a45e9 HTTP/2.0 
https://MYDOMAIN/administrator/index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin.display&element=jform_images_image_intro&mediatype=images&converted=1&context=22&plugin=browser&standalone=1&15f462eea0ca946548e59238cbe7080b=1&client=1&fieldid=jform_images_image_intro&ismoo=0&folder=   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0    150     nginx SSL/TLS access

2022-12-13 06:21:13 
Error   
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
27342#0: *1962880 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream               
nginx error

2022-12-13 06:21:13 
Error   
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
27342#0: *1962880 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream               
nginx error

2022-12-13 06:21:13 
Error   
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
27342#0: *1962880 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream               
nginx error

2022-12-13 06:21:14 
Access  
63.228.99.999 (MY LOCAL IP ADDRESS) 
200 
GET /components/com_jce/editor/libraries/fonts/wfeditor.woff HTTP/1.0   
https://MYDOMAIN/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/css/plugin.min.css?6bdb53c47cde613b1f4e5d6e909815aa    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0    
632     
Apache SSL/TLS access
```

Comment: I would be looking at a firewall or mod_security in Apache as it smells like something is blocking the requests. Any recent updates in the server software?

Comment: There was an update a few weeks ago, unfortunately the sites on this server aren't updated (content) that often, so we didn't notice it when that happened.
And mod_security was my first thought, so I disabled it for a few minutes and tested and still had the same problem (then quickly re-enabled it).

Comment: I wish I could into out exactly what the "111: Connection refused" is related to. I've searched for quite a while with no definitive (or even helpful) info to track this down.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it appears that this issue is specifically related to some conflict between JCE Editor and some configuration on the server.
After uninstalling JCE (and just using TinyMCE editor) the editor areas are working - both the content and the image selections. And there are no errors appearing in the server log.

Additionally, we had tried on one domain to use the Quantum Manager extension. That extension was having issues also and showing similar nginx errors.

So it must be something with the add-in media managers (both JCE and Quantum manager) that are having conflicts with some setting on this server.

As J3 is nearing end-of-life and as we haven't been able to pinpoint exactly what server configuration was causing this issue, we're just going to consider that we found a 'work-around' that should resolve the issue until we can upgrade to J4 (which doesn't appear to have the issue).

Comment: Given the cross over of products having the issue all related around the 'images' I would be looking at what plugins are being installed by JCE which are then being called by the other two extensions. Maybe put things back to where they are failing and then disable the JCE plugins one by one until you identify the culprit.

Comment: Working with the JCE team to try to identify the problem now.